# Issue with jQuery 'else'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but only the first half of my script is being picked up. I've tried various combinations and can only get one of the if statements to work at a time.

```
if (!$('#LocalDelivery').is(":checked")) {
    $('#datepicker').attr("value", "");
    $('#LocalDate').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#LocalDate').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 
}    
else
{
if (!$('#StandardShip').is(":checked")) {
    $('#LocalDate').attr("value", "");
    $('#datepicker').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#datepicker').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name'));      
}
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
To clarify, I do understand 'else' means either one or the other. The problem here is that even if the condition is met for the 2nd if statement, it doesn't execute. I can only get a reaction from one if statment at a time using the above code or any similar variation that I have tried.

Comment: `To clarify, I do understand 'else' means either one or the other. The problem here is that even if the condition is met for the 2nd if statement, it doesn't execute.` You're contradicting yourself. You say you understand that only one can work, but then you say you're surprised by it.

Comment: By the way, the language is JavaScript. `else` is a Javascript construct. jQuery is just a JavaScript library you're using.

Comment: The code inside the second if-statement will execute only if `#LocalDelivery` is NOT checked AND #StandardShip is NOT checked. Is that what you want? Could you clarify when you want the code in the second if-statement to execute? Also, are these radio buttons or checkboxes?

Comment: Hi John, thanks so much for your response. I guess I wrote this all wrong. What I want is for the first if to execute only if #LocalDelivery is checked and the 2nd if to execute only if StandardShip is checked.

Comment: Lightness-I guess I'm not being clear but other people seem to understand what I'm asking so if you would like to help, please see the other responses and my comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
if ($('#LocalDelivery').is(":checked") == false) {
    $('#datepicker').attr("value", "");
    $('#LocalDate').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#LocalDate').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 
}    
if ($('#StandardShip').is(":checked") == false) {
    $('#LocalDate').attr("value", "");
    $('#datepicker').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#datepicker').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 

}
```

You can also change `.is(":checked")` with `.attr("checked","checked")`.

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that you are trying to implement two specific values in the same element `#datepicker` and thats what must be causing your first conditional not to get picked.

What i mean is that when both checboxes are not checked you are trying to put TWO values in ONE element `#datepicker`.

The above means that the logic of your code is wrong.You could instead for example have only one checkbox and do the following:

```
 if ($('#LocalDelivery').is(":checked") == false) {
        $('#datepicker').attr("value", "");
        $('#LocalDate').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
        $('#LocalDate').attr('name',
        $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 
    } else {
        $('#LocalDate').attr("value", "");
        $('#datepicker').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
        $('#datepicker').attr('name',
        $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 

    }
```

Comment: Stefanos thank you very much for your response. As I said in my reply to Man of Snow, "This is one version I tried but went ahead and gave it another shot. Unfortunately it only picks up the last if statement so still not working." Any other ideas?

Comment: If you would like go and use `else if` and tell me the result. Also is there any other code involved in this conditonals that you havent posted here?

Comment: Hi Stefanos! I tried your above else if code and it's just picking up the first if statement. I have a lot of other script on this page but none that should affect this and there are no issues in the console. ???

Comment: Check my last edit on my answer and please tell me if thats the case.

Comment: I agree, my logic is totally wrong. I should probably go about this another way altogether. In the meantime I did attempt your code and it isn't working in my current setup. I think it might be just the wrong way to do this.

Comment: You can make an other post to ask people to help with the logic part as long as you explain what exactly is the thing you are trying to achieve. I hope i helped you in some way.

Comment: Stefanos, I have marked your answer as correct (since it is) but went ahead and created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fGLNh/. I think it's going to just have to be done another way but I thought it might be worth pursuing. Basically just have two text inputs that I'd like to share the same values. Realize this is a krudge but it's an unusual situation. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Stefanos, just saw your last comment and yes you have been very helpful. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (!$('#LocalDelivery').is(":checked")) {
    $('#datepicker').attr("value", "");
    $('#LocalDate').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#LocalDate').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 
}    
if (!$('#StandardShip').is(":checked")) {
    $('#LocalDate').attr("value", "");
    $('#datepicker').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#datepicker').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 

}
```

If you're using else, the second `if` will be executed if the first one returns `false`, so what you had is what you should've expected.  The first `if` returns true, so the second one is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is one version I tried but went ahead and gave it another shot. Unfortunately it only picks up the last if statement so still not working.

Comment: F12 and check to see if there are any red X's sometimes you don't spell something correctly and it bricks part of the code

Comment: Chitowns I have no issues in the console. Thanks for your help! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

And that is how it is supposed to work. If first half is `true` then the `else` block would not be executed. Every time only one block will be executed. Never both

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I understand this. What I am saying is when the other condition is met it doesn't pick it up. Only one of the if statements are ever functional at one time.

Answer (score 1):

**That is what `if` and `else` mean.**

```
if (A) {
   B
}
else {
   C
}
```

If `A`, then `B`, *otherwise* `C`.

If you didn't intend the "otherwise" portion of this little equation, then do not use `else`!

Comment: Hi, per my comment to laaposto, "Sorry I was unclear. I understand this. What I am saying is when the other condition is met it doesn't pick it up. Only one of the if statements are ever functional at one time."

Comment: @susan: Sorry but that doesn't make any sense. Did you perhaps miss that your second `if` is inside the `else` from the first `if`?

Comment: Hello Lightness..I am sure I missed a lot or I would have figured this out without help. ;-) If you can post an answer to explain that would be most helpful.