# Assign value from one input to another input using jQuery...not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of radios (#LocalDelivery  and #StandardShip) related to a couple text inputs (#LocalDate and #datepicker). Then, off in another section is another text input with class productAttributeValue.

If LocalDelivery is chosen/checked, I need its input, #LocalDate to get the value and name from the input with class productAttributeValue. Or, if #StandardShip is chosen/checked I need its input, #datepicker, to get the value and name from the input with class productAttributeValue.

I have tried various combinations of the following:

```
if (!$('#LocalDelivery').is(":checked")) {
    $('#datepicker').val("");
    $('#LocalDate').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#LocalDate').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name')); 
}    

if (!$('#StandardShip').is(":checked")) {
    $('#LocalDate').val("");
    $('#datepicker').val($('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').val());
    $('#datepicker').attr('name',
    $('.productAttributeConfigurableEntryText div.productAttributeValue input[type="text"]').attr('name'));      
}
```

Per my other thread, [Issue with jQuery 'else'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940124/issue-with-jquery-else), this method isn't working. According to the answers given there, this is the wrong method entirely but I'm not sure how else to go about this.

Here is a fiddle:

[This is my glorious Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/susan999/fGLNh/8/)

---

**EDIT:**
Per beautifulcoder's comment I have added a click function to both radios. While it would be preferable for the inputs to populate their value without clicking first, this is the first solution I've had that works. Created a fiddle here, hope it helps someone else:

[My amazing working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/susan999/4LZGA/)

Comment: soemthing like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3A3S5/1/ ?

Comment: @suzan: Where is your event listener?

Comment: @suzan, add a click event handler on each radiobox, check for syntax errors

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `!` operators. But after this code executes, you will end up with two input elements with the same name.

Comment: Hello all and thank you so much for your responses, much appreciated. Arun, this isn't really what I'm looking for but I'm pretty inexperienced so could be I just don't understand it. I anyway tried it but it didn't work. Alex, thank you for your comment. As beautifulcoder suggested I added a click handler and it works very well. Edited my answer above with a Fiddle. Would be nice to have the fields populate without the click but it's not crucial. Super happy to have this working, thanks very very much. John, appreciate the comment but removing the !operators didn't seem to make a difference.